# System.PlatformNotSupportedException Compiling C# code at runtime .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-10.0, system-codedom-compiler

Trying to compile simple C# code at runtime on .NET Core but have this error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on
> this platform.'

on this line:

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

My code:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

string code = @"
    using System;

    namespace First
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
            " +
                "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");"
                + @"
            }
        }
    }
";


CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);


if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
}


Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
Type program = assembly.GetType("First.Program");
MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");


main.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: Yeah, sure. Did you actually check the official documentation for the CompileAssemblyFromSource method? What does it say?

Comment: @myskullcaveisadarkplace Yeah, sure. But I didn't notice anything that can help me. Can you say me what do you mean?

Comment: Read the remarks section of the method documentation...

Comment: @myskullcaveisadarkplace  Noticed, thanks. Maybe you know the alternative?

Comment: Hmm, depends. There is Roslyn aka the .NET compiler platform SDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/compiler-api-model, https://www.pmichaels.net/2021/08/29/compiling-code-files-in-c-using-roslyn/). But it's quite a bit more advanced than the outdated CodeDomProvider, and i am not going to pretend that i have a good grasp on it. If that is too complex or time-consuming to master, perhaps there is some library out there that hides the complexities of Roslyn behind a simple(r) API just for some straightforward compiling of C# source code, but i don't know of any :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using the Roslyn compiler.  You'll need to add references Microsoft.CodeAnalysis and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp for the following example to work.  Note, that the `RoslynCompiler` class loads the assembly dynamically.  You can modify the class fairly easily to use a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream` if you want to save the compilation to disk for reuse.

**Sample Usage of RoslynCompiler Class (below)**

```
    string code = @"
    using System;

    namespace First
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");
            }
            public static void WithParams(string message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
    }
";

var compiler = new RoslynCompiler("First.Program", code, new[] {typeof(Console)});
var type = compiler.Compile();
    
type.GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, null);
//result: Hellow World!

// pass an object array to the second null parameter to pass arguments
type.GetMethod("WithParams").Invoke(null, new object[] {"Hi there from invoke!"});
    //result: Hi from invoke
```

**Roslyn Compiler Class (Quick and Dirty Example)**

```
public class RoslynCompiler
{
    readonly CSharpCompilation _compilation;
    Assembly _generatedAssembly;
    Type? _proxyType;
    string _assemblyName;
    string _typeName;
    
    public RoslynCompiler(string typeName, string code, Type[] typesToReference)
    {
        _typeName = typeName;
        var refs = typesToReference.Select(h => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(h.Assembly.Location) as MetadataReference).ToList();
        
        //some default refeerences
        refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(System.Runtime.GCSettings).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location), "System.Runtime.dll")));
        refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Object).Assembly.Location));

       //generate syntax tree from code and config compilation options
        var syntax = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
        var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(
            OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary, 
            allowUnsafe: true,
            optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release);

        _compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(_assemblyName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), new List<SyntaxTree> { syntax }, refs, options);
    }

    public Type Compile()
    {
        
        if (_proxyType != null) return _proxyType;
        
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var result = _compilation.Emit(ms);
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                var compilationErrors = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                        diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error)
                    .ToList();
                if (compilationErrors.Any())
                {
                    var firstError = compilationErrors.First();
                    var errorNumber = firstError.Id;
                    var errorDescription = firstError.GetMessage();
                    var firstErrorMessage = $"{errorNumber}: {errorDescription};";
                    var exception = new Exception($"Compilation failed, first error is: {firstErrorMessage}");
                    compilationErrors.ForEach(e => { if (!exception.Data.Contains(e.Id)) exception.Data.Add(e.Id, e.GetMessage()); });
                    throw exception;
                }
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            _generatedAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);

            _proxyType = _generatedAssembly.GetType(_typeName);
            return _proxyType;
        }
    }
}
```

**Performance Tip**

If performance matters, use delegates as opposed to `Invoke` as follows to achieve near pre-compiled throughput:

```
void Main()
{
    string code = @"OMITTED EXAMPLE CODE FROM SAMPLE ABOVE";

    var compiler = new RoslynCompiler("First.Program", code, new[] { typeof(Console) });
    var type = compiler.Compile();  
    
    // If perf matters used delegates to get near pre-compiled througput vs Invoke()
    var cachedDelegate = new DynamicDelegateCacheExample(type); 
    
    cachedDelegate.Main();
    //result: Hellow world!
    
    cachedDelegate.Main("Hi there from cached delegate!");
    //result: Hi there from cached delegate!


}
public class DynamicDelegateCacheExample
{
    delegate void methodNoParams();
    delegate void methodWithParamas(string message);
    private static methodNoParams cachedDelegate;
    private static methodWithParamas cachedDelegateWeithParams;

    public DynamicDelegateCacheExample(Type myDynamicType)
    {
        cachedDelegate = myDynamicType.GetMethod("Main").CreateDelegate<methodNoParams>();
        cachedDelegateWeithParams = myDynamicType.GetMethod("WithParams").CreateDelegate<methodWithParamas>();
    }
    
    public void Main() => cachedDelegate();

    public void Main(string message) => cachedDelegateWeithParams(message);
}
```

Comment: See my answer for a different approach for System.Runtime & getting a `MetadataReference` from an assembly inside a published self contained .exe.

Answer (score 1):

With .net core netstandard and publishing to a self contained exe there are a couple more tricks you'll need;

```cs
public static ModuleMetadata GetMetadata(this Assembly assembly)
{
    // based on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36590#issuecomment-689883856
    unsafe
    {
        return assembly.TryGetRawMetadata(out var blob, out var len)
            ? ModuleMetadata.CreateFromMetadata((IntPtr)blob, len)
            : throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not get metadata from {assembly.FullName}");
    }
}

#pragma warning disable IL3000
public static MetadataReference GetReference(this Assembly assembly)
    => (assembly.Location == "")
        ? AssemblyMetadata.Create(assembly.GetMetadata()).GetReference()
        : MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assembly.Location);
#pragma warning restore IL3000

public static Assembly Compile(string source, IEnumerable<Type> references)
{
    var refs = new HashSet<Assembly>(){
        typeof(object).Assembly
    };
    foreach (var t in references)
        refs.Add(t.Assembly);

    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic
            && a.ExportedTypes.Count() == 0
            && (a.FullName.Contains("netstandard") || a.FullName.Contains("System.Runtime,"))))
        refs.Add(a);

    var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default
        .WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.Latest);

    var compileOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
        .WithAssemblyIdentityComparer(DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default);

    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Dynamic",
        new[] { SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(source, options) },
        refs.Select(a => a.GetReference()),
        compileOptions
    );

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var e = compilation.Emit(ms);
    if (!e.Success)
        throw new Exception("Compilation failed");
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var context = new AssemblyLoadContext(null, true);
    return context.LoadFromStream(ms);
}

// for dynamically implementing some interface;
public static C CompileInstance<C>(string source, IEnumerable<Type> references)
{
    var assembly = Compile(source, references);
    var modelType = assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(t => typeof(C).IsAssignableFrom(t)).Single();

    return (C)Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
}
```